# How to use express react views lib with ES6 React code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I tried to use express-react-views as an express view engine, but it only compile React code in JSX without ES6. How can i switch to ES6 please.

This is the code im using for Error page:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Error extends Component {
  render() {
    return <p>{this.props.error}</p>;
  }
}

export default Error;
```

This is the error im having:

```
    SyntaxError: /Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/views/error.jsx: Unexpected token (4:8)
[0m [90m 2 | [39m
 [90m 3 | [39m[36mclass[39m [33mError[39m [36mextends[39m [33mComponent[39m {
[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 4 | [39m  state [33m=[39m {}[33m;[39m
 [90m   | [39m        [31m[1m^[22m[39m
 [90m 5 | [39m  render() {
 [90m 6 | [39m    [36mreturn[39m [33m<[39m[33mp[39m[33m>[39m{[36mthis[39m[33m.[39mprops[33m.[39merror}[33m<[39m[33m/[39m[33mp[39m[33m>[39m[33m;[39m
 [90m 7 | [39m  }[0m
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClassProperty (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2571:50)
    at Parser.parseClassProperty (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:6157:20)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClassBody (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2516:34)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClass (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2406:8)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1843:19)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:5910:22)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2268:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/mac/Documents/ReactJS-dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1778:8)
```

Comment: what version of node are you using

Comment: im using v8.11.4

Comment: woah that is one crazy error message. can you show us some more code? I've never seen something spit out that kind of output before. it's not an es6 problem, that stuff is not javascript at all